# Transfer Uint8Array from browser to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typed-arrays

I have a `Uint8Array` containing raw pixel data (RGBA) I need to send to my node server for processing. I convert it to a blob on the browser and send that through ajex, but retrieving the data on the node side is being problematic. I can get the blob as a `Buffer` through `req.files.image.data` but how do I convert that back in to the same sequence I had with the `Uint8Array`?

On the browser:

```
sendBlob(new Blob(data, {type: "application/octet-stream"}), ...)

function sendBlob (blob, name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let data = new FormData()
    data.append('image', blob, name)
    data.append('width', 640)
    data.append('height', 427)
    $.ajax({
       url: '/upload',
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       error: reject,
       success: resolve
    })
  })
}
```

On node server:

```
lwip.open(req.files.image.data, {
  width: parseInt(req.body.width),
  height: parseInt(req.body.height)
}, (image, err) => ...)
```

This complains `Buffer size does not match width and height` as `req.files.image.data` is the blob not the wrapped `Uint8Array`.

Comment: the obvious first step is to not pass the blob, but to make sure to tell Node that this is in fact a uint8array by converting it with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-arraybuffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in how I was creating the blob. I passed a single TypedArray, blob only knows how to store an array of TypedArrays. So it was converting my data into a string before storing it in the blob.

The solution is to simply wrap the TypedArray in an array.

```
sendBlob(new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-stream"}), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Uint8Array` from the posted data.

```
let data = new Uint8Array(req.files.image.data);
lwip.open(data, {
  width: parseInt(req.body.width),
  height: parseInt(req.body.height)
}, (image, err) => ...)
```